# Can someone explain to me why is "position:absolute" used with the ":before" selector without having any content?

Tags: html

I can't understand the point of this code that is given as an example in developer.mozzila.org.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="fname">First name *: </label>
  <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" required>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
input + span {
  position: relative;
}

input + span::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 5px;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input:invalid + span::before {
  content: '✖';
  color: red;
}

input:valid + span::before {
  content: '✓';
  color: green;
}
```

I understand why they would want to use relative to position the "span" content, but i can't understand the point of the second code paragraph, in which they use the ":before" selector, and then inside, they again change the position to "absolute" without adding any content.

Isn't "before" and "after" used to add content? In this example, no content is added, so what is the point of adding position:absolute? What is being positioned? And isn't the "position: absolute" just re-writing the above "position:relative"?

I've tested this code by removing the position absolute, and it works the same way. In fact, adding position absolute only makes it more difficult to position the content.

They've given this explanation:

> We set the span's to position: relative so that we can position the
> generated content relative to them. We then absolutely position
> different generated content depending on whether the form's data is
> valid or invalid — a green check or a red cross, respectively.

But this explanation makes no sense to me. They are saying they've set the position to relative in order to position the generated content, presumably they mean the check mark, relative to "them", by "them" presumably they mean the "span"? This makes no sense to me. The content is not separately positioned to their container, so what are they talking about? And what 'different generated content' having to be positioned with absolute are they talking about? I don't see any different generated content.

I would appreciate if somebody explain to me their reasoning behind this convoluted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two rule-sets, which are conditional on the input being `:valid` or `:invalid`, add the content to `::before`.

The rule-set you are confused about applies no matter if it is `:valid` or `:invalid` and sets rules which are used for both conditions.

---

> The content is not separately positioned to their container, so what are they talking about?

The generated content is the pseudo-element containing the `✖` or the `✓`.

That generated content is `position: absolute` so is positioned with respect to the nearest ancestor that is *positioned*: i.e. the `span`.

> And what 'different generated content' having to be positioned with absolute are they talking about?

`✖` is different to `✓`.

Comment: So i think i understand part of my question. The 2nd rule sets adds position absolute without content, and then when the content is added below, it already is positioned. But what about the first position relative? That's what i don't understand right now.  1st of all, doesn't the second position rewrites the first? And how can content be relative to the span? I mean, the content itself is INSIDE the span, right? So, how can the content be relative to its own container? How is span the ancestor of the content when its container? Could you please try to explain this part in a more simple way.

Comment: Also, on a side note, the "plus" selector works when the first element is "true" right? I.e. there is a condition that the first element is true or valid for the rules to apply to the second attached element, correct?

Comment: The `span` element and the `span::before` pseudo-element are different elements, so no, one doesn't overwrite the other.

Comment: "So, how can the content be relative to its own container?" — How far is it from its container's left edge? The top edge? the right edge? The bottom edge.

Comment: "How is span the ancestor of the content when its container?" – The same way that my father is my ancestor.

Comment: I struggle immensely to understand this. I think i understand how it works, but i don't understand what is the point of making the pseudo-class content position absolute, since the span element does not have any content. So changing the position of span changes the position of the pseudo-class content too. So why is span set to relative if it doesn't have any content, and then a pseudo-class selector adds another content with position absolute? I do not comprehend the point of this. Why not just change the position of the span, since it has no other content but the added content?

Comment: "So changing the position of span changes the position of the pseudo-class content too" — nothing is changing the position of the span, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: "So why is span set to relative if it doesn't have any content" — It has content: The generated content in the `::before` pseudo-class.

Comment: Also, i thought that making the position of an element absolute means that the element is taken out of the normal doc flow, and it's now relative to the html page. But in this case, if the the span has a position relative, making the pseudo-class content absolute position moves the content relative to the span content, and not the html page. Why is that? Why is it not taken out of the doc flow again? Is the pseudo-class content inside the span?

Comment: "Why not just change the position of the span" — How?

Comment: "Also, i thought that making the position of an element absolute means that the element is taken out of the normal doc flow," — It does

Comment: "and it's now relative to the html page" — No. Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their nearest positioned ancestor… which is the span… I said that in the answer already.

Comment: "nothing is changing the position of the span" - what do you mean by that? I just make the input + span position relative, and then use left and right to position in where i want it to be. Changing the position of span also changes the later added pseudo-class content of the checkmark and x sign.

Comment: span does not have any content. So targeting the span targets the x and checkmark.

Comment: You aren't doing that.

Comment: What do you mean im not doing that? What am i doing then?

Comment: well if it does, then why is setting left 0 on an absolute position not moving it to the beginning of the page, but to the beginning of the span element? So its not taken out of the doc flow, or it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Im going to need more than one sentence answer here.

Comment: You don't understand what "taken out of document flow" means. It means "has no effect on the position of elements which are not its descendants" not "Is positioned with respect to the viewport". I've already said, twice, that it is positioned with respect to its nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: okay- and what about the other issue? Since the span does not have any content, why not just move the span which will also move the content generated by the pseudo-class? You said im not doing that - what am i doing then? Why add a position to the later added content if the span itself does not have any content, and moving the span moves the later added content too?